# Prevent repeated '+' character simultaneously on Key Up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had regular expression which is `onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^aA0-9 +]/g,'');`
Which is allow string only number with '+' symbol i.e 1+2+3

I had functionality of + for combine.
But in some time it allow example '+1' and also '1++3+' or '+++4+5'.

How to prevent repeated '+' and on start with '+' on keyup event so that my functionality will work.

Any suggestion.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the event listener properly using Javascript, and then you can replace multiple pluses in a row with a single plus by matching `\++` (literal plus, repeated) and replacing with `+`. Also note that `0-9` in a character set reduces to `\d`, which is a bit nicer to read:

```
element.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  this.value = this.value
    .replace(/[^aA\d +]/g,'')
    .replace(/\++/g, '+');
});
```

You might also want to check for spaces around pluses so as to avoid, for example, `a+ +a`. If that's the case, then you can use:

```
.replace(/ *\+[ +]/g, ' + ')
```

That will replace optional spaces, followed by a plus, followed by any combination of pluses and spaces, with a single plus surrounded by a space on each side. (of course, you could also replace with a plus alone, without spaces, if you wanted)

Comment: Thank It work fine. But what if i want to prevent + at start . What is regular expression. Any help

Comment: To prevent pluses at the beginning of the string, use `.replace(/^\++/g, '')`. `^` matches the position at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var element=document.getElementById("txtSum");
element.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  this.value = this.value
    .replace(/\s/g, '') // Removes space
    .replace(/^\++/g, '') // Remove begining with +
    .replace(/[^aA\d +]/g,'') 
    .replace(/\++/g, '+'); // Replace multiple +
   
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtSum"/>
```